# Redirect if a value matches with any cell in a specific range - google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

.gs (updated)

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html').evaluate()
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function doPost (e) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var values = sh.getRange(2, 12, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
// Logger.log(values);


try {    

var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("OTP");
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
});
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);

var value = newRow[1];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
if (values[i] == value) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Confirmation.html').evaluate()
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
} else {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Error.html').evaluate()
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}}}

catch (e) {
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

finally {
lock.releaseLock()
}}
```

The purpose of the above code is to check if the value `newRow[1]` matches with any cell value in the range (L2:L) in Sheet1, then redirects to Confirmation.html, otherwise, to Error.html based on the if statement in the code

Now the problem is; only if `newRow[1]` == first/top value in the range (L2:L), the user is redirected to Confirmation and any other value below that in the range redirects the user to error

For example:
If we have 4 values in the range L2:L like that:
L2: John
L3: Mike
L4: Jenny
L5: Tom

If a user submits John as `newRow[1]`, redirected to Confirmation and that is correct with no problem, but

If a user submits Mike or Jenny or tom, redirected to error and this wrong because the new submitted value is still in the range and should redirect the user to Confirmation as well

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the function called? Redirect from where?

Comment: I updated the question with the complete gs for more clarification. Thanks for interest

Comment: Is OTP a linked sheet.

Comment: Set `target="_top"`

Comment: "Is OTP a linked sheet" no it is a tab in the same sheet

Comment: (Set target="_top") returns this error {"result":"error","error":{"name":"Exception"}}

Comment: But I still receive the new submits in the sheet so I guess the real problem is with the second part of the google script that checks for any matches for the new input and trigger the if statement. That's why I was pasting only this part at the first place before updating the question

Comment: I am trying to Logger.log the variable values but it gives me null instead of returning the actual values in the sheet so I think this may be the problem for some reason the script is not able to see the values that are needed to match the new submitted value with

Comment: Try `createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e ,'message':e.message}))` and post the error `message`. Also, address me `@TheMaster`, when you reply to me.

Comment: Hello @CenEg, just like mentioned above, what error message are you receiving? Cheers!

Comment: I added some modifications to the script and now I think that the problem is in looping through the range of data. Please see the updated question @TheMaster

Comment: I added some modifications to the script and now I think that the problem is in looping through the range of data. Please see the updated question @ale13

Comment: So what was the original problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: The main problem I was redirected to a blank page whether the submitted value matches with any value in the range or not and when I was logging the values, I was getting null. What have I done: I moved the variable values outside of the try { @TheMaster

Comment: And to be honest I don't understand why? if you can tell, I would be so grateful @TheMaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the data first before checking for the value instead of a for-loop:

```
if(values.flat().includes(value)){
  return /*confirmation page*/
} else {
  return /*error page*/
}
```

The for loop did not work, because the logic is amiss: Your code states that:

```
for each value in values    
  if this value(in loop) is equal to value, I'm checking    
    end this function and return confirmation html
  else
    end this function and return error html
```

Whatever the case, the function will end after checking the first value. The correct way to do such a for loop would be:

```
var isValueInColL = false;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (values[i][0] == value) {//added [0]
    isValueInColL = true;
    break;// no need to check rest of col L
  }
}
var html = isValueInColL ? 'Confirmation' : 'Error';
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(html).evaluate()
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Comment: Already included. I was just pasting the most relative part to the question to make it shorter as much as possible. Now you can see all of it. Thanks

Comment: Do you think this is may be the reason of the getting a blank page after form submit ??

Comment: Yes. google sites to be specific but so far still not embedded. I am testing using the script URL from Publish, Deploy as web app ..

Comment: Yes it worked thanks a lot @TheMaster - can you please tell me why the looping did not work because I was thinking this what the loop does ??

Comment: @CenEg `return` ends a function. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form.html');
}

function doPost (e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  if(!e || !e.parameter) {
    Browser.msgBox('No Parameters');
    return;
  }
  var doc=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=doc.getSheetByName('OTP');
  var headers=sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nextRow=sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var newRow=headers.map(function(header) {return (header=='Timestamp')?new Date():e.parameter[header];});
  sheet.getRange(nextRow,1,1,newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
  var sheet1=doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values=sheet1.getRange(2,12,sheet1.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var value=newRow[1];
  for (var i=0;i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0]==value) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Confirmation');
    }else {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Error');
    }
  }
}
```

Try your html this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="script URL" target="_self" method="POST">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter OTP" required name="OTP">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Some of your html tags were out of place for example the body tag doesn't belong above the

Comment: I tried Cooper but no luck as well. Everything is working except the form is redirected to a blank page. I updated the question with complete gs for more clarification. Thanks for interest

Comment: "Why did you do this code this way knowing that there is only one column in your data" I always use this in similar cases when I need to search a specific range for a certain value and get the row number for the cell that is matched that's why I thought of using the same concept and include the if statement in case of any matching

Comment: I just copied from one of my other projects that requires an evaluate and I did not think it might cause a problem even when not needed in this one. Do you think this is might be the reason ?

Comment: I deleted a bunch of comments so we don't have to move to chat.  But take a look at my answer now and lets try it that way.  Hopefully, we will at least get some different kind of error.

Comment: If this doesn't get us anywhere I'd like to see images of the pertinent sheets.

Comment: I tried your changes but unfortunately still the same. Screenshots from both tabs are added. Please note that values in the range L2:L in Sheet1 are generated by an array formula if this changes anything. thanks again for interest Cooper

Comment: To be honest with you this is too much work to set up and debug.  I'm going to have to leave it to you.